# Проблемы с ЧПУ на php и .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Здравствуйте, учу php, пытаюсь без фреймворка создать свою единую точку входа с ЧПУ для опыт.

Все работает так:

.htaccess перенаправляет все запросы на страницу index.php. А уже index.php работает как единая точка входа
данные с index. php:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' ) {

        include 'html/main.inc.php';

    } else {

    $page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
    $pg   = explode('?', $page, 2);

    if ( count($pg) >=2 && $filename = 'html/'.$pg['0'].'./'.$pg['1'].'.inc.php' && file_exists($filename) ) {

        include $filename;

    } elseif ( $filename = 'html/'.$pg['0'].'.inc.php' && file_exists($filename) ) {

        include $filename;

    }

    if ( file_exists('html/'.$pg['0'].'.inc.php') ) {

        include 'html/'.$pg['0'].'.inc.php';

    } else {

    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != 'html/'.$pg['0'].'.inc.php') {

        include "html/error.inc.php";

    }

}
}
```

И хочу реализовать такое, что когда переходят допустим на страницу "cat.inc.php" - она проходит через index.php и отдает страницу уже с таким без окончания, то есть "cat". Так вот хочу реализовать такое что допустим я выгружаю информацию с mysql через get и ссылка имеет такой вид site.com/cat?link=rapap, а хочу чтоб было так site.com/cat/rapap
.Пробовал гуглить, но все настройки через htaccess не работают

Comment: Поставьте после `$pg   = explode('?', $page, 2);` команду `var_dump($pg);` и посмотрите, что за бяка :) у вас будет в массиве при запросе к `site.com/cat?link=rapap`. Возьмите лучше готовый роутер https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute и ни каких get-переменных в запросе!

Comment: @Visman я бы взял роутер, но не особо понимаю как им пользоваться .Тем более хочу набраться опыта в этом самописе - пусть и говнокоде. $pg - эта переменная доставляет адрес страницы до знака ? то есть, без этой переменной если будет url с get параметрами тогда будет переводить в 404

Comment: Вы посмотрели, что вам выдает var_dump()?

Comment: @Visman да, он разбивает на ? в массив